# How can i use the touchpad while typing? (Lenovo)

Tags: windows, drivers, touchpad, synaptics-touchpad

i have a pretty old lenovo ideapad running Windows 10 22H2 and this thing's annoying me, the fact that the synaptics driver is old and there's no PalmKms registry key to enable the touchpad while typing, and i have palm tracking set to low, the driver version is 7.5, here's msinfo32

[image: MSInfo32 page 1]
[image: MSInfo32 page 2]
[image: MSInfo32 Synaptics Info]
[image: Synaptics Driver Settings]

**EDIT : It turns out my fix didn't work** it only worked on the login screen tho

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to Lenovos answer [How to enable and disable your touchpad](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/vid100752-how-to-enable-and-disable-your-touchpad)

I have had problems with drivers on some idea pads not allowing me to turn off the touchpad. I had to update to go back to an older driver.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: This is actually not the answer i was looking for, i already know about the f6 key, but i'm looking to always keep the touchpad enabled when typing something? ex : i'm playing a game and i can't move my mouse to look around when holding the w key